# Banach fixed point theorem and Picard-Lindelöf applied to this equation (explanation needed)

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems

Consider the following equation which holds for all $w$ in some space,
$$\langle v(t), w \rangle = \langle v(0), w \rangle - \int_0^t \langle F(s,v(s)), w \rangle$$
where $\langle F(s,v),w \rangle$ is locally Lipschitz continuous in $v$.

> This integral equation has a solution by help of Banach's fixed point theorem in analogy to the existence theorem of Picard-Lindelöf.

I don't see how this is similar to the equation $y'(t) = f(t, y(t))$ or its integral, because we have the duality pairing $\langle v(t), w \rangle$ here. How to overcome this?

Source is Section 2.1 of http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10492-012-0004-0.

*edit*: Maybe I put the integral inside the duality pairing and then apply the ODE existence theory to the first component of the duality pairing??

**EDIT**: some text from the paper:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Tyh5.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/APkUp.jpg
[http://imgur.com/drlwRgv](https://imgur.com/drlwRgv)

Comment: You cannot do as you suggest as that would need Lipschitz continuity of $F$, while you only have Lipschitz continuity of $\langle F(\cdot, \cdot), w\rangle$. This is weaker. But the proof should push through almost unchanged.

Comment: With your last sentence I guess you mean that I can use the Banach fixed point theorem on my first displayed equation. I don't see what the operator should be defined..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the article it is written $w_j$ is a **finite dimensional** **basis** of a finite dimensional space $A := span(w_1...w_k)$ and that the equation you mention has a solution $[0, T]\to A$ (only, it is written just before (2.1))

The author showed that $\|\langle F(s,u),w\rangle - F(s,v),w\rangle\|\le C\|u-v\|$ for all $u,v$ in a bigger space than $A$. Then, as Alex has written, let 
$$
F_j(y) = \langle v(0),w_j\rangle + \int_0^t \langle F(s,y), w_j\rangle ds.
$$
If you assume that $F_j\colon A\to C([0,T])$; let $y_n:\mathbb R\to A$ be given, and $(F_j(y_n))_{j\le k}$ is a family of $k$ elements, there exists then a unique $y_{n+1}(t)\in A$ s.t.
$$
\forall j, t,\qquad F_j(y_n)(t) = \langle y_{n+1}(t), w_j\rangle
$$
because the family $(w_j)_j$ is a basis!! This transition $y_n\to y_{n+1}$ is now clear, and with the relation
$$
\forall j, \langle y_{n+1}, w_j\rangle = F_j(y_n)
$$
you prove that there exists a fixed point for the sequence $(y_k)$...

Note: It seems for me that the finite basis hypothesis is the key for the proof... Moreover, i'm not totally sure about the spaces above, but you will correct me if needed...

**EDIT:** how to get the fixed point? As usually: Let $\|\cdot\|$ be the norm as explained in the article (like $L^{m'}$) norm and define the new norm in time
$$
\|f\|_T = sup_{t\in[-T,T]}(e^{-Lt}\|f(t)\|)
$$
Moreover, as the deimension is finite and all norm are equivalent, the $\|\cdot\|$ norm in $A$ is equivalent to the norm defined by $f\in A$, $\sum_j |\langle f, w_j\rangle|$. Therefore, exists $C'$ such that
$$
\|y_{n+1}(t) - y_n(t)\| \le C' \int_0^t \|y_n(s)-y_{n-1}(s)\|ds
$$
Then,
$$
\begin{split}
\|y_{n+1}-y_n\|_T &\le C'\sup_{[-T,T]} e^{-Lt}\int_0^t\|y_n(s)-y_{n-1}(s)\|e^{-Ls}e^{Ls}ds \\
&\le C'\|y_n-y_{n-1}\|_T \sup_{[-T,T]} \frac 1Le^{-Lt}[e^{Lt}-1] \\
&\le \frac{C'}{L}\|y_n - y_{n-1}\|_T
\end{split}
$$
Thus for $L<C'$ the sequence is contracting. We just have to check that the space $\mathcal C([0, T]; A)$ with $\|\cdot\|_T$ is a Banach space. $A$ with $\|\cdot\|$ is a Banach (it is $L^{m'}$ projected on a closed space), thus $C([0,T],A)$ with this sup norm is also a Banach: Everything is fine and you can apply Banach fixed point theorem!

Comment: Thanks. So you are just defining $y_{n+1}$ componentwise right? Its $j$th coefficient is equal to $F_j(y_n)$ . OK. What would $y_0$ be, the starting point?

Comment: Also, can you expand on how to prove that there is a fixed point for the $y_n$?

Comment: I edited the text for Banach fixed point theorem. Moreover, $u_0$ which is given in the statement of Lemma 2.1, $u_0$ is in $L^{m'}$, the starting point is rather its projection on $A$. Are you okay now?

I also don't like the articles that give absolutely no details at all on how to proceed to prove "simple" things. However it gives good exercises, but only if we have time...

Comment: Thanks that's a great help. I think the space $A$ should be equipped with the norm $H^1 \cap L^{m'}$, because the Lipschitz condition in the proof of Lemma 2.1, at the end, involves the space $H^1$ on the right hand side, so your first inequality involving $C'$ would make sense with that norm.

Comment: And I guess the map is $T(y_n) = y_{n+1}$. I've not seen a "discrete" mapping like this before.

Comment: Yes, it goes from $C([0,T],A)$ into $C([0,T],A)$. It is implicitly defined but it still exists! - for the space $A$, I guess in the article they write it $X_p \cap L^{m'}$ (i dont know what $X_p$ is)

Comment: Thank you. Just one last question: The equation the author actually considers is of the form $$\langle \varphi(u(t)), w_j \rangle = \langle \varphi(u_0), w_j \rangle - \int_0^t \langle F(s,u(s)), w_j\rangle$$. So our $y_n$ is really $\varphi(u_n)$, and the author writes $u_n$ (and not $\varphi(u_n)$) in terms of the basis $w_j$. Since $\varphi(u_n)$ is no longer in $A$, is $\varphi(u_{n+1})$ or $u_{n+1}$ still well-defined given $u_n$?

Comment: You are right; I read in the article $\varphi(u) = u^{m'-1}$, $m\ge 2$ thus $m'-1 \in ]0,1]$ and $\varphi$ is inversible, $\varphi\colon L^{m'}\to L^{m}$, $\varphi^{-1}:L^{m'}\to L^{m}$. Therefore the contraction sequence $u_n \to u_{n+1}$ is constructed using this sequence: $u_n\in L^{m'} \to \varphi(u_n) = y_n\in L^{m} \to F_j(y_n) \to y_{n+1}\in L^m \to u_{n+1} = \varphi^{-1}(y_{n+1})\in L^{m'}$. Note here that we have to change the previous definition of $A=L^{m'}$ to $A = L^m$ because $y_n\in L^m$ now.

Comment: Hmm, but $y_n = \varphi(u_n)$ is not finite dimensional, right? so it is not clear to me that $y_{n+1}$ is well-defined because $y_n$ is not finite-dimensional.

Comment: Oh, my fault : $A$ is $X_p \cap L^m$ and $y_n$ is the *projection* of $\varphi(u_n)$ on $A$, while $u_{n+1}$ is simply the inverse by $\varphi$ of $y_{n+1}$.

Comment: So then $y_{n+1} \in A$ is computed by $\langle y_{n+1}(t), w_j \rangle = \langle \varphi(u_0), w_j \rangle - \int_0^t \langle F(s, u_n(s)), w_j \rangle$. This is well-defined given a $u_n$. This gives us a $y_{n+1}$. Maybe we need to set $u_{n+1} = P_k(\varphi^{-1}(y_{n+1}))$ the *projection* of the inverse..

Comment: Hmm, no I think projecting it as I suggest won't give work... can't show that a fixed point corresponds to a solution. However $u_n$ really ought to be finite-dimensional..

Comment: Things are a bit messy now. Indeed, there is no $\varphi$ in the $F$... Define $y_{n+1}$ s.t. $\langle y_{n+1}, w_j\rangle = \langle \varphi(u(0)), w_j\rangle - \int_0^t \langle F(s, \varphi^{-1}(y_n)), w_j\rangle$. The right-most term is still Lipschitz because a) $u\to\langle F(s,u),w_j\rangle$ is Lipschitz as we already said, and b) $\varphi^{-1}$ is Lipschtiz : indeed, it is what they show in the first part of proof of Lemma 2.1!!! Once the whole sequence $(y_n)$ is constructed you can set $u_n := \varphi(y_n)$, and what you prove here is that the projection of $(u_n)$ converges.

Comment: Ok so I define $y_{n+1}$ as in your comment. Then I define $u_n := \varphi^{-1}(y_n)$ and $u:=\varphi^{-1}(y)$ where $y$ is limit of $y_n$. Then I consider $\langle \varphi(P_k u_{n+1}), w_j \rangle = \langle \varphi(u_0), w_j \rangle + \int_0^t \langle F(s, \varphi^{-1}(P_k u_n)), w_j \rangle$ and need to show that $P_ku_n \to P_ku$ and this gives existence. There is one problem: in attempting to get the bound on $y_{n+1}-y_n$, I get $|y_{n+1}(t)-y_n(t)|_A \leq C\int_0^t |\varphi^{-1}(y_n)-\varphi^{-1}(y_{n-1})|_{H^1}$. But we cannot use "the Lipschitz continuity of $\varphi^{-1}$" as they...

Comment: ...state in Lemma 2.1 because they prove $|u-v| \leq C|\varphi(u) - \varphi(v)|$ for $u, v$ belonging to the finite dimensional space. We want to take $u=\varphi^{-1}(y_n)$ and $v=\varphi^{-1}(y_{n-1})$ but these are not in finite-dimensional space. Sorry for prolonging this... maybe I should start another thread.

Comment: No, what we have only proven is that there exists a sequence $(u_n)$ and $u$ in $L^{m'}$ such that $P_k\varphi(u_n) \to P_k\varphi(u)$, with $P_k$ the projection operator $L^{m}\to A=X_p\cap L^m$. Also, be aware that the general equation is $\langle P_k\varphi(u_n), w_j\rangle = \langle P_k\varphi(u(0)), w_j\rangle + \int_0^t \langle P_k F(s, u(s)), w_j\rangle ds$ and $|y_{n+1}-y_n|_A\le C \int_0^t \|\varphi^{-1}(y_{n+1}) - \varphi^{-1}(y_n)\|_{m'}$ ! There is no need to open another thread as your question is very specific and we are close to the answer.

Comment: Hmm, when you say "also, be aware that the.." and you write that equation, are you saying that eg. $\langle \varphi(u(t)), w_j \rangle = \langle P_k \varphi(u_n(t)), w_j \rangle$ with $P_k$ as you defined it. I guess this $P_k$ is different to the projection the authors make (which is onto $X_p \cap L^{m'}$..

Comment: Oh ok, sorry then. What is $P_k$ in the article?

Comment: there is no $P_k$ as such in the article, I just meant the projection onto a finite-dimensional subspace of $X_p \cap L^{m'}$. I wish authors had given more details!!

Comment: Ok then I did a small mistake and thought that $X_p \cap L^{m'}$ is of finite dimension

Comment: I posted a question on MO (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/168300/existence-of-an-integral-equation-faedo-galerkin-banach-fixed-point-picard-li). It's worth asking because there may a different way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot read the linked paper, I would have to buy the paper :). If I understand right, the formulation you give is a weak formulation for the integral equation
$$v(t)=v(0)+\int_{0}^{t}F(s,v(s))d s,$$ which is again a formulation for the ode you mentioned. In my opinion, it is essential that you name the test space for $w$ as well as what they (the authors) understand by a weak solution of this type of ode. Now let $w$ be fixed, then, we have to show that the mapping
$$
C_{w}:A\rightarrow A,\ C_{w}(x)=\langle v_{0},w\rangle+\int_{0}^{t}\langle F(s,v(s)),w\rangle ds
$$
is a contraction for $A$ a proper Banach space (you should know, which space to pick, or the paper should mention this fact). Let $\|\cdot\|_{A}$ be the norm of the space $A$, we have for $x,y\in A$ and $w$ arbitrary but fixed:
$$\|C_{w}(x)-C_{w}(y)\|_{A}\leq \int_{0}^{t}L\|x-y\|_{A}\ d s \|w\|\leq Lt\|x-y\|_{A}\|w\|,$$
applying Cauchy Schwarz (if we have an inner product) and using the local Lipschitz continuity. So for sufficiently small $t$ this is a contraction also depending on $w$. Now one might be able to assume $\|w\|=1$ (depends on the definition of the weak solution) and we have the contraction, and thus a solution in the - still to be specified - space $A$.

Of course, first of all you have to show, that the $C_{w}$ is mapping $A$ to $A$, i.e. $C_{w}$ is a self-map. But I cannot show this, since I do not know $A$....

Maybe this is a bit helpful or gives some ideas for the solution...

Yours,

Alex

Comment: Hi Alex thanks for answering. My biggest issue is: with your proof, we obtain a fixed point $y$ of $C_w$. But all we get is that $y = C_w(y) = \langle y_0, w \rangle + \int_0^t \langle F(s,y(s)),w$ which does not have the same left hand side since the duality product is missing. I hope I'm not being silly..

Comment: riem, you should get something like $\langle y,w\rangle=C_{w}(y)$, which should be fine?!

Comment: Now I understand, your problem is that $C_{w}:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and not as I claimed $C_{w}:A\rightarrow A$. Hm, strange..., right now I do not have an idea how to get the operator well defined.

Comment: Please see my edited post -- I added some images with the text which may be helpful!